# Парсинг веб-страницы, после выполнения кода выходит одна строка

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

https://plastinfo.ru/trade/sell/raw/     - сайт с которого нужно извлечь данные

Для получения строки из таблицы использую такой код:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_htlm(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    div = soup.find('div',class_ = 'trade_board_border')
    table = div.find('table')
    tbody = table.find('tbody')
    row = tbody.findAll('tr')

    print(row)

def main():
    parse(get_htlm('https://plastinfo.ru/trade/buy/raw/'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В результате выполнения выдает только 1ую строку из таблицы.

```
[<tr class="odd"><td>13:25</td><td><a class="trade" href="/trade/buy/raw/526624/" onclick="pageTracker._trackEvent('trabe', 'buy', 'object', 526624);"></a></td></tr>]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в результате были все строки ?
Использую Python 3, BeautifulSoup 4, Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал самостоятельно получить интересующие вас элементы. Нарвался на ту же проблему.
Похоже, остальные строки таблицы подгружаются не при отлучении `response`, а позже.

Добавление `page1`, `page2` и т.д. в хвост ссылки также ничего не дает.

Придется вам переключаться на `selenium` для симуляции пользователя и фактической загрузки данных на странице.